# How to remove trailing characters after a blank space in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I've a string, '12/10/2010 00:00:00'. How do I show this as ''12/10/2010' using C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try:

EDIT:

```
DateTime d;
DateTime.TryParse("12/10/2010 00:00:00", d);
d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: -1, I think you should check your code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx

Comment: @Codesleuth - Tru dat. Hasty code typing early in the morning. Thanx.

Answer (score 6):

This takes the first half of your string before the space:

```
   string formatedDt = "12/10/2010 00:00:00".Split(' ')[0];
```

Comment: Doesn't compile since string.Split is a member method and not a static function.

Answer (score 6):

Everyone else has answered the question directly, however I have a feeling that what you really need is to become familier with the various ways `System.DateTime` provides to generate a string representation:

[DateTime.ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx)

[DateTime.ToShortTimeString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring.aspx)

[DateTime.ToString(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

```
string s =  "12/10/2010 00:00:00";
s = s.Substring(0,s.IndexOf(" ");
```

Comment: I think this one doesn't work if the string contains no spaces at all.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - none of these solutions work if there is no space. Why is this answer different?

Comment: String.Split returns the whole string as [0] if the input string doesn't contain one of the split-chars.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - I took the question "How to remove trailing spaces after a blank space, c#" to mean that there would always be at least one space.

Comment: I think your answer is perfectly reasonable for the question asked.  In the general case, though, it's important to note that if there isn't a space in the given string, Substring will throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException since IndexOf will return -1.  For the sake of promoting safe code, I think it's at least a good idea to check the return from the IndexOf before calling Substring.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
"12/10/2010 00:00:00".Split(' ')[0]
```

this returns the whole string if it doesn't contain a space.

Or if you need other behavior in case of a missing space you can do this:

```
string s =  "12/10/2010 00:00:00";
int spaceIndex=s.IndexOf(" ");
if(spaceindex>=0)
{
    return = s.Substring(0,spaceIndex);
}
else
{
    //Handle the case without space here
    //For example throw a descriptive exception
    throw new InvalidDataException("String does not contain a space");
}
```

Comment: If there is no space, the returned string is "12/10/201000:00:00" which is not what OP wants.

Comment: It's unclear what the OP want. Both returning the whole string and thus making the operation idempotent and throwing a descriptive exception seem reasonable to me. Throwing an ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception on the other hand doesn't seem reasonable to me.

Comment: There must be a space because OP gave space in example input.